# Laravel : how to get the old session after redirecting from Paypal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When using Paypal express checkout method, I'm providing the return url as http://example.com?sid=$sid

In Cakephp I could set the session_id to $_GET['sid'] in the AppController's before filter.

But how should I get the old session using that $_GET['sid'] in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the internal session ID using [`Illuminate\Session\Store#getId()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Session.Store.html#_get) (see [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session#getId()`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_getId), which `Store` extends), but if the session ID is regenerated by Laravel internals, you may end up mistakenly invalidating the operation.

Ideally, you would create your own token for verification, something along the lines of:

```php
// Generate a random token, and place it into the session
Session::put('paypal_token', str_random(40));
// Formulate the URL
$paypal_url = route('root', array('token' => Session::get('paypal_token'));
// This will generate something like "http://example.com/?token=[randomstring]"
```

Which you can then verify:

```php
if (Input::query('paypal_token') === Session::get('paypal_token')) {
    // Token valid
} else {
    // Token invalid
}
```

See: [`str_random()`](http://laravel.com/api/function-str_random.html), [`Illuminate\Session\Store`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Session.Store.html), [`Illuminate\Http\Request#query()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Http.Request.html#_query), [`Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator#generate()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.html#method_generate)

**Edit**: I was mistaken about getting the internal session ID.  I've updated it above.  Laravel actually uses Symfony's `HttpFoundation` component to generate session IDs (see [doc](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.html#method_regenerate), [source](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/v2.4.1/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L199))